# how show flash error messages in Rails 3 using Ajax and Jquery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

my controller create function is

```
def create
  @group = Group.new(params[:group])
  @group.company=current_user.company
  respond_to do |format|
    if @group.save
      format.html { redirect_to(@group, :notice => 'Group was successfully created.') }
      format.js
    else
      flash.now[:error]=@group.errors.full_messages
      format.html { render :nothing => true }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

create.js.erb file is

```
$('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @group))%>').appendTo('#groups');
$("#new_group")[0].reset();
```

Comment: please put your code in code tags ({} symbol)

Answer (score 10):

Here is my solution to this Issue....
I put these in all my js.erb files

```
$('#flash').html("<%= escape_javascript raw(flash_display) %>");
```

With this Helper

```
def flash_display
  response = ""
  flash.each do |name, msg|
    response = response + content_tag(:div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}")
  end
  flash.discard
  response
end
```

this works well with the flash div already set up in layout

```
<div id="flash">
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 2):

Create a div for the flash when the page initially loads:

```
<div class="flash-error"></div>
```

set a javascript variable for the flash in the js.erb file.  Then check for a value and update the "flash-error" div using javascript.  It will probably look something like this:

```
$('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @group))%>').appendTo('#groups');
$("#new_group")[0].reset();
var flashError = "<%=flash.now[:error]%>";
if (flashError){
  $(".flash-error").html(flashError);
}
```